# In XSLT nested foreach loop always return first element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

XLST receiving the date from apache-camel in below formate.

data format

```
<list>
  <linked-hash-map>
    <entry key="NAME">test1</entry>
  </linked-hash-map>
  <linked-hash-map>
    <entry key="NAME">test2</entry>
  </linked-hash-map>
</list>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='linked-hash-map']">
       <tag1>
            <xsl:value-of select="string(//*[local-name()='entry'][@key='NAME'])"/>
       </tag1t>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT always returns the first element.

```
<tag1>test1<tag1>
<tag1>test1<tag1>
```

What is wrong in above xslt and help generate xml with all elements.

Comment: It is not clear why you match on `*` (which means inside of the template you have some element as the context node) but then use two absolute paths starting with `//*`, both will select from the document root node and not relative to any context node established, so neither the `select` of the `for-each` nor the one the `value-of` makes sense as an absolute path, I suspsect `match="list"` on the template, `select="linked-hash-map"` on the `for-each` and `select="entry[@key = 'NAME']"` on the `value-of` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because path expressions starting with "//" select from the root of the document tree, you are selecting the same nodes every time in your `xsl:value-of`; and in XSLT 1.0, if you select multiple nodes, only the first one gets displayed.

Methinks you're using "//" because you've seen it in example code and don't actually understand what it means...

Within `xsl:for-each`, you normally want a relative path that selects from the node currently being processed by the for-each.

You've also probably picked up this `*[local-name()='linked-hash-map']` habit from other people's code. With no namespaces involved, you can safely replace it with `linked-hash-map`.